# Azure function - location of 'azure-functions-host' folder

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-appservice

I have developed Azure Function which uses log4net for logging and it is configured via file.
Locally it works okay, but when I deploy it on Azure I receive error: **System.Private.CoreLib: Could not find file '/azure-functions-host/log4net.config'**

I am using Linux App Service and I'm unable to find folder 'azure-functions-host' on the file system.

Comment: In Visual Studio, the "Build Action" and "Copy to Output directory" will be property for such config files in the project. It is not clear which IDE you are using, may be you need to turn on such a flag so that your `deployment` to azure includes that config file.

Comment: Yes, I have set both of these options in VS and the file is located in the root folder after deployment. If i try the Windows Azure function error is then System.Private.CoreLib: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.3.1\32bit\log4net.config'.

Comment: can you try to get the log4net `repository` as shown in this [example](https://blog.devmobile.co.nz/2019/03/26/azure-function-log4net-configuration/) ?Also, you can open the Kudu console for your app service that hosts your function app and check if the log4net config file is having the right configuration.

Comment: Few minutes ago I've solved this issue. The solution which you have linked works OK for Windows (both for config location and log folder). In Linux it works okay for config location but for the log folder location I had to set it to "/home/site/wwwroot/Log4Net/function.log"


Please post you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the function app, the log4net is to be initialized using the `repository` object as shown in this [example](https://blog.devmobile.co.nz/2019/03/26/azure-function-log4net-configuration/). And also, if `linux` is used for hosting the App Service, then the path for the log file to be set as "/home/site/wwwroot/Log4Net/function.log"